# Emacs w3m export highlighted area as text

Tags: emacs, copy-paste, w3m

How can I copy text from emacs-w3m when the content is placed in a table? Currently, it copies the table-formatting and boundaries as well. Is there a export as text for w3m?

Answer (score 0):

No. w3m.el uses the w3m browser to render web pages, dropping the text into an Emacs buffer. Tables do not have any additional formatting associated with them, so Emacs has no way of distinguishing them from surrounding text.

The only solution would be to write your own code to filter out the table formatting and boundaries. There is no pre-made solution.